# Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app

Tags: kubuntu, email, google, gmail, kmail

Yesterday, I've discovered that KMail (5.7.3) on my Kubuntu 18.04 doesn't synchronize with Google mail inbox.
I tried to re-create the gmail account, but after logging into Google I received the following message:

> Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
>
> This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Is that global problem that KMail stopped working with Google or just mine?
Is it possible to solve/workaround it?
Maybe it's possible to bypass KMail wizard and log into Google account using an app password?

Comment: Probably a global problem. Months ago I received an email from Google saying that in the near future the Email native app in my phone will no longer be supported.

Comment: You can enable using gmail with untrusted apps.

Comment: @Pilot6 Seems that Google made it impossible to switch untrusted apps on if you have 2FA enabled...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been observing the KDE bug regarding this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=404990. To summarize discussions in the bug's comments:

1. The problem is global.
2. The bug is affecting newly created Gmail accounts in KMail as well as existing accounts.
3. The workaround is possible. It should work if you:

   - turn on "less secure apps" in your Google account settings
   - set authentication method to PLAIN in KMail
   - use application password to login to gmail servers.

   People in the linked bug writes that it works. However, I've noticed that you have to have 2FA disabled on your Google account. Otherwise Google won't let you to enable "less secure apps". I haven't tried the workaround because I don't want to lose security 2FA gives you.
4. KDE community is working on the problem. The request has been sent to Google for recognizing KMail as a secure app.

For the explanation of why this is happening see this Daniel Vratil's blog post: https://www.dvratil.cz/2019/08/kontact-google-integration-issue/

Answer (score 0):

Check your gMail on another device. Is it prompting you to approve a login?

It sounds like you may have to wait for Google to verify KMail as an app that can use Google Sign In.

Comment: No, it works on my phone. I think it may be global problem. I've just found this topic on KDE forum: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=215&t=161620