# sign in with google temporarily disabled for this app in KUBUNTU Dolphin after re-installing

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, google-drive, kmail, kwallet

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04,

[image]

I had this same issue before. I noticed that, when ever I try to connect by WiFI it asks for the KDE Wallet password, and also had the same issue in getting connected with GoogleDrive. Then, I re-installed OS and I didn't see the KDE Wallet when connecting with Wi-Fi;  GDrive also connected OK.

After reinstallation of Kubuntu 18.04, the problem returns.

[Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164372/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app)

I have gone through this, but the problem didn't get solved.

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows you use 18.04, which is not the latest Kubuntu version, so the text was amended accordingly. 19.10 is the latest Kubuntu version, as you will see when you go to https://kubuntu.org/

Comment: Though its not a latest, what is making that problem? Because same thing worked before. I didn't update the flash drive. Same flash drive with same OS.