# Can't Copy, paste or delete the files in NTFS partitions

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, security, dolphin, kwallet

I have two HDD. One has the Win 10 and the other has the Kubuntu 18.4 version. I flashed the Kubuntu OS before two months. I had the same problem. Which is that I cant able to copy or paste in the NTFS Win 10 bootable HDD from Kubuntu. So I flashed the same Kubuntu OS in same HDD where I installed the Kubuntu before. After that I tried to copy and paste in NTFS HDD and it worked. Later I messed up with Kubuntu and again I installed same Kubuntu OS which I had before. Now facing the same issue. One thing I noticed that, when I faced the same issue I saw the KDE wallet asks to save the Wifi password while connecting and google drive didn't get connect in Dolphin. And also the KDE wallet didn't head up when it worked well. What would have caused this problem.

Comment: You've provided no details as to how you mounted it or what the messages said. If you mounted it RW, did it give in messages reasons why it can't be mounted RW & that it thus mounted it RO because *fs* was inconsistent (hibernated etc) or contains errors & RO prevents further issues etc.  ie. when `mount` occurs messages are your best clue - read them.

Comment: @guiverc I didn't see any error message. That's why I simply posted as text. You can also go through this previous post.[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210548/sign-in-with-google-temporarily-disabled-for-this-app-in-kubuntu-dolphin-after-r) Here I got some error message, so I uploaded Screen Shots. But here I didn't see any message.

Comment: If you `mount` using a GUI tool, the messages will be in logs so you need to hunt for them (like you do in windows too).  Try `dmesg` or `journalctl` .. or just `umount` and then `mount` via terminal and the message appear on your terminal without having to look :)

Comment: @guiverc But I ddn't mount using any tool. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36XCh.png) Please have a look at this pic. At left corner we can see 2 `New Volume` drivrs. I just did this `Rght Clik->UnMount` and again `Right Click->Mount`. Same thing I did before installing this. May b as u said I will try `dmesg` or `journalctrl`. If I re-Install, I wont get this issue. But I woul like to know what is causing tis issue. As I mentiond in previous comment, it is the 1st problem and this is 2nd, I'm facing two types of same problems so far which I faced at the 1st time of installation.

Comment: I consider `dolphin` a GUI tool, but that's just the wording I used. Personally I'd use terminal (I'm confident in term anyway, and the `umount` & `mount` are as quick via commands for me as clicking menu options in `dolphin` plus I get to see any messages.  I mentioned `dmesg` first as that's were I'd expect to see the message; you could run `dmesg` first (get a *feel* for what logs look like), then `umount` & `mount` using `dolphin` & `dmesg |tail` to look again at logs and the last message(s) should be related to `mount`. If you don't see it, then look in `journalctl`.

Comment: @guiverc  4.978437] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
 [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
[sda] Write Protect is off
[sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[sdb] Write Protect is off

Comment: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[sda] Attached SCSI disk
new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
 sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3 sdb4 sdb5 sdb6
 [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

Comment: @guiverc I did as you said. In terminal `dmesg` There I got these. Can you please tell me whats wrong in that. Sorry I cant find what's wrong in that. SDA has the linux and sdb has the windos.

Comment: If you provide more information, please edit your question and place it there. The extra detail is next to impossible to read in comments so I won't try. We can help you to edit questions/answers & format it correctly there; comments can only be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Ubuntu, you should by default be able to read and write on a partition that is formatted in ntfs, the file system of Microsoft Windows. The condition, however, is that the volume should be "clean", i.e. in a properly closed, cohesive state.

In a dual boot system, the ntfs partition may not be clean if Windows "Faststart" is enabled, or if the Windows system is hibernated instead of powered down. In these conditions, files on the volume may still be open. While Windows will cope with that on the next restart. Linux will mount such drives as read-only, or not at all.

Thus, to solve the issue:

- Load MS Windows. Have the partition checked with the Windows drive checking tool.
- Make sure "fast start" in Windows is disabled (only enable it if you do not plan to use the drive with Linux).
- Fully shut down MS Windows (i.e., no Sleep or Hibernate).

Next time you boot into Ubuntu, the drive should mont without issues.